# Trying to create a sub set of data from a list of strings in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently working on a c# questionnaire builder and ran into an issue....

​My code is as follows:

```
private void loadQuestions() 
{
    Questions allQuestions = new Questions();
    allQuestions.loadQuestionData(questionnaireID, -1);
    string questionnaireHtml = "";

    try
    {
        // get a list of all groupIDs
        var groupIDs = allQuestions.Select(groups => groups.groupID).Distinct();

        foreach (int groupID in groupIDs)
        {
            // extract a subset of the questions based upon 
            // groupID to build each group container
            try
            {
                Questions groupQuestions = (Questions)allQuestions
                    .Where(questions => questions.groupID == groupID);

                questionnaireHtml += buildGroup(groupQuestions);
            } 

            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }

        QuestionsContainer.InnerHtml = questionnaireHtml;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        // display friendly error message
    }
}
```

What's going on here is all questions are loaded into memory, grouped together by what group the question belongs to (as well as some other logic). My issue is when i'm trying to create a subset of the data (for that particular group), I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[MedVerifyPlusFacilities.QuestionnaireHandler+Question]' to type 'Questions'

The object `Questions` is simply a list of `Question` objects. If I try an explicit cast, it still bombs out:

```
Questions groupQuestions = (Questions)allQuestions
    .Where(questions => questions.groupID == groupID);
```

In my troubleshooting, I came across that `foreach` and LINQ's `Select`/`Where` functions do not necessarily return the same data type, I'm just not sure how to go about resolving this.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using a `List<Question>` instead of a custom implementation for `Questions`? If so, please state the reason and provide the code for the `Questions` class. It's possible you'll need to provide custom casting ability for your class, or provide a constructor that takes in a `List<Question>` and returns an instance of `Questions`.

Comment: You state that, *"The object `Questions` is simply a list of `Question` objects."*, yet that clearly isn't the case since you show that it has a `loadQuestionData`  method, which isn't a member of `List<T>`.

Comment: I do have one custom function in that class, LoadQuestionData() that grabs the data from the database and converts it to a Question object, and then adds it to the Questions object, which is defined as a List(Questions>. I also plan on expanding that class in the near future to be used elsewhere in my app

Answer (score 0):

changing the groupQuestions declaration to:

```
Questions groupQuestions = new Questions( allQuestions.Where( questions => questions.groupID == groupID ).ToList() );
```

as well as adding to my Questions class:

```
        public Questions( List< Question > questions ) {
            this.questions = questions;
        }
```

and the error disappeared.